# How to use extract tables from websites using python pandas by https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

Tags: pandas

Right now I'm using this to get the table from this website

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_html('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
for data_cases in data:
    print(data_cases)
```

Error:
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: Forbidden

Thank's

Comment: I'd guess they rejecting user agent strings that don't look like real browsers to prevent people scraping the page like this (i.e. they don't want you to do this!). Try setting a user agent string from a real browser.

Comment: Better yet, licence their data from them properly! However [their FAQ](https://www.worldometers.info/licensing/faq/) does say they don't offer a coronavirus data API at the moment.